# Load Bitmap success but width and height is 0?

Tags: windows-phone

Mycode load bitmap from resource:

```
   Uri _uri = new Uri("e.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
   BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(_uri);
   int iW = bmp.PixelWidth;
   int iH = bmp.PixelHeight;
```

bmp is loaded successful but both iW and iH is 0. I don't know why ? Can you tell me how i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you may have to find where PixelWidth and PixelHeight are defined.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? PixelWidth and PixelHeigh are property of BitmapSource class:   
        public int PixelHeight { get; }
        public int PixelWidth { get; }